# Why is the finallyDecrypt method in this code undefined?

Tags: javascript, method-chaining, chain

My app receives a base64 encoded value that is also encrypted. The data can come in a few different ways so I wanted to create chain-able methods to keep the code clean and modular.

I want to be able write: `decryptionChain.decodeBase64(b64Value).stringToBuffer().finallyDecrypt();`

When I run the code, the last property method "finallyDecrypt" returns as undefined.

Why is the "`finallyDecrypt`" method coming back as undefined? The rest all works and if I run `encryptionChain.decodeBase64(b64Value).stringToBuffer()` I get back the Buffer I expect.  It is only when the `finallyDecrypt` is chained in that I error out.

Here is the code:

```
   function decrypt(encrypted) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, password, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(encrypted.tag);
    var dec = decipher.update(encrypted.content, 'hex', 'utf8');
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return dec;
}

var decryptionChain = {

    currentValue:"",

    decodeBase64: function (encryptedValue){
        this.currentValue = new Buffer(encryptedValue.toString(), "base64");
        return this;
    },

    stringToBuffer: function() {
        if (this.currentValue) {
            myBuffer = JSON.parse(this.currentValue, function (key, value) {
                 return value && value.type === 'Buffer'
                    ? new Buffer(value.data)
                    : value;

            });

        }
        return myBuffer;
    },

    finallyDecrypt : function(myBuffer){
        if(myBuffer){
        decrypt(myBuffer);
        }
        return this;

    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chaining works by returning `this` from each method (which points back to the `decryptionChain` object).

`stringToBuffer`, however, returns `myBuffer`, so you're trying to call a method named `finallyDecrypt` on that buffer (which doesn't have that method, hence the error).

If you want it to work with chaining, use something similar to how you're dealing with `currentValue`:

```
stringToBuffer : function() {
  ...
  this.myBuffer = myBuffer;
  return this;
},
finallyDecrypt : function() {
  if (this.myBuffer) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification. finallyDecrypt is no longer undefined when I make the change you suggested. However, one side effect of this seems to be that assigning the Buffer to 'this' changes the buffer back to an object which causes the decryption to fail (since it expects a buffer).  How would I got about preserving the buffer as a buffer in this pattern?

Comment: @Cyph assigning a buffer to a variable shouldn't convert anything (but `JSON.parse()` may)

Answer (score 0):

The stringToBuffer() function returns a Buffer (or it may return nothing if this.currentValue is falsey).  The function you're trying to call is not in Buffer, it's in decryptionChain, so when you try to call a non-existing function on Buffer, it's telling you it's undefined.

Notice in decodeBase64(), you store this.currentValue and then return this.  That's why the next chain works, because the decryptionChain object is being returned.

So stringToBuffer() could store it's result in this.bufferedResult, and then stringToBuffer() could return this.